# React Native ListView Datasource with Firebase

Tags: listview, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-listview

I'm trying to list my Firebase database items in real time in my React Native ListView. However, with the following code, I'm getting an error saying that "undefined is not a constructor" when I initialize the dataSrouce state in the constructor. What should I do to make it work? thanks.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2})
    };
    this.itemsRef = this.props.firebaseApp.database().ref();
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.listenForItems(this.itemsRef);
}

renderItem(item) {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight>
        <View>
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
}

listenForItems(itemsRef) {
    itemsRef.on('value', snap => {
      var items = [];
      snap.forEach((child) => {
        items.push({
          name: child.val().name,
          description: child.val().description,
          dateID: child.val().dateID,
          schema: child.val().schema,
          _key: child.key
        });
      });

      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(items)
      });
    });
}

render() {

    var TouchableElement = TouchableHighlight;
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
     TouchableElement = TouchableNativeFeedback;
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
          datasource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderrow={this.renderItem.bind(this)} />
      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please post the component code as well.. class definition

Comment: firebaseApp is passed in through a prop as PT.object, other than that everything else is fine

Comment: You found the solution?

Comment: Nope, still waiting for one

Comment: may be it is because `datasource` and `renderrow` should be camel-cased, like: `dataSource` and `renderRow` , in `<ListView dataSource={...} renderRow={...}`

Answer (score 0):

Yes [@Cherniv is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470633/react-native-listview-datasource-with-firebase/41765435#comment69123077_40470633), it should be `renderRow` and `dataSource` under the list view component.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try~

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2})
    };
    this.itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('test');
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.listenForItems(this.itemsRef);
}

listenForItems(itemsRef) {
    itemsRef.on('value', snap => {
      var items = [];
      snap.forEach((data) => {
        items.push({
          name: data.val().name,
          description: data.val().description,
          dateID: data.val().dateID,
          schema: data.val().schema,
          _key: data.key
        });
      });

      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(items)
      });
    });
}

render() {

    var TouchableElement = TouchableHighlight;
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
     TouchableElement = TouchableNativeFeedback;
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
          datasource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderrow={this.renderItem.bind(this)} />
      </View>
    );
}

renderItem(items) {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight>
        <View>
          <Text>{items.name}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
}
```

the example for Structure data

```
{
  "test": {
    "postKey or userId here": {
      "name": "...",
      "description": "",
      "dateID": "",
      "schema": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for simple data.

This is my constructor:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var firebase = Firebase.database().ref();
    this.FirebaseRef = firebase.child('Users');
    this.state = {
        IsValid: false,
        Name: "",
        Post: {
            PostText: "",
            postUri: ""
        },
        Surname: "",
        uri: "",
        DataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 != row2
        })
    }
    this.items = [];
  }
```

I fill my `listviewDataSource` in

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.FirebaseRef.on('child_added', (dataSnapshot) => {
        this.items.push({
            id: dataSnapshot.key,
            IsValid: true,
            Name: dataSnapshot.val().Name,
            PostText: dataSnapshot.val().PostText,
            postUri: dataSnapshot.val().postUri,
            Surname: dataSnapshot.val().Surname,
            uri: dataSnapshot.val().uri
        });
        this.setState({
            DataSource: this.state.DataSource.cloneWithRows(this.items)
        });
    });
```

And my `renderRow`

```
 renderRow(rowData) {
    return (
      <ScrollView ContainerStyle={styles.ScrollView}>
        <Text>{rowData.Name} {rowData.Surname}</Text>
        <Image source={{ uri: String(rowData.uri) }} style={styles.Photo} />
        <Text>{rowData.PostText}</Text> 
        <Text>{rowData.postUri}</Text> 
        <Image source={{ uri: String(rowData.postUri) }} style={styles.postPhoto} /> // I can not reach my post Uri
        </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```